# Player 1 controls player 2 and vice versa

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

When i create room, and player 2 connect to room, i control him, and he controls me. What should I do?
Player controller combined with unity3d fps basicrigidbodypush script and mouse look.
Unity 3d 2020.3.26f version, development mode off. Video of it (left button and input field is creating room, right button and input field is joining room)https://dropmefiles.com/XPPa3.
In resources folder there is player prefab.
Player prefab contains mesh renderer, player controller script (below), character controller, photon view, photon transform view classic (synchronize position and rotation turned on), rigidbody and photon rigidbody view (all enabled)

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotonView view;
    public LayerMask pushLayers;
    public bool canPush;
    [Range(0.5f, 5f)] public float strength = 1.1f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;
    public GameObject camera;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    public Transform PlayerBody;
    public float MouseSensitivity = 100f;
    float xRotation = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (view.IsMine) {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) {
            velocity.y = -7f;
        }
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) {
            CursorTrigger();
        }
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * MouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * MouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        PlayerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        }
    }
    private void PushRigidBodies(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if (view.IsMine) {
        Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
        if (body == null || body.isKinematic) return;
        var bodyLayerMask = 1 << body.gameObject.layer;
        if ((bodyLayerMask & pushLayers.value) == 0) return;
        if (hit.moveDirection.y < -0.3f) return;
        Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0.0f, hit.moveDirection.z);
        body.AddForce(pushDir * strength, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if (view.IsMine) {
        if (canPush) PushRigidBodies(hit);
        }
    }

    public void CursorTrigger() {
        if (view.IsMine) {
        Cursor.visible = !Cursor.visible;
        
    }

}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I usually go about this in a different way. Try the following:

```
if(!view.isMine)
{
    return;
}
```

And then continue with your code afterwards.

Comment: this doesnt work :(

Comment: Have you tried to disable the entire PlayerController script if(!view.isMine)?